# GCP is restarting my VMs in the middle of the day

Tags: google-cloud-platform, virtual-machines, gcp

I have a fleet of `e2-highmem-2` GCP VMs.  I expect that these VMs will not be restarted randomly.  However, that seems to be what is happening.  Every two weeks or so GCP is restarting my VMs.

The VMs run Windows Server 2016.  Availability policy is Standard.  On host maintanence is set to `Migrate VM Instance (recommended)`.  Automated restart is set to `On`.  Windows Update on the machine is set to Manual.

Given this, my understanding is that if there is host maintanence a live migration will happen and no downtime should happen.  And yet my servers are getting rebooted!  Why is that?  What do I need to do to make this stop?  This doesn't happen in Azure which also has Live Migration.

Does Live Migration for GCP not work for Windows Server?  Is it crashing and getting restarted upon Live Migration?

Comment: In your GCP VMs it is the same specs from your Azure instance ? monitor the utilisation of your GCP instance while Live Migration, to verify if the specs are to accommodate the process of the Live migration.

Comment: @JeffreyD. Yes they are the same.  When you say monitor utilization while Live Migration - do you mean check if there is load during the migration?  Also how can I set it so that all host maintanence only happens on the Weekend?

Comment: since this is a Windows Server, you can monitor the utilization from Task Manager > Performance, you can monitor your GCP instance while the process is on-going. To verify if the specs are problematic. 

and also verify the [events logs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/protect/tech-ref/bitlocker/server-event-logs) from windows server to check and investigate what are the exact time of force shutdown of this instances.

Comment: @JeffreyD. The problem is I have no idea when google is going to do it (How do I get this information) and so I can't monitor it

Comment: access the GCP instances VMs, investigate and monitor from the servers. find event logs from windows servers, to verify what are the main issues of this.